# "You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity" Unable to start activity

Tags: android, android-appcompat, android-toolbar

I'm getting this error using android-support-v7-appcompat and trying to add a toolbar to my activity.

values/styles.xml

```
    <resources>

 <resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppTheme.Base" />

    <style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>

    </style>
</resources>
```

menu_main.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_refresh"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:showAsAction="always"
        android:title="Refresh"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:title="Settings">
    </item>

</menu>
```

My activity XML is including in the first place the

```
   <Android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar

         android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:background="@android:color/black"

         />
```

My java activity extends  AppCompatActivity and has these code lines:

```
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

 @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

In the manifest

```
android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
```

Does anyone has some idea please?

Comment: If you are using toolbar, you need to set NoActionBar for theme, Currently you are using DarkActionBar.

Comment: I've just tried what you advised but I received the same error :(

Comment: is that your full `activity.xml`? post your entire file

Comment: no, it's very big, so I just put the part of the toolbar. Do you need any info on the xml?

Comment: I think you already have `NoActionbar` right? Put the entire styles for that activity.

Comment: This is my styles.xml: <resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppTheme.Base"/>

<style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
            <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    
    </style>
</resources>

Comment: It's basically the same I put in the question but with noactionbar

Comment: You should add it in the question, not here.

Comment: Updated, sorry I'm new on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just found out what was wrong. In the manifest, I was specifying `android:theme="@style/AppTheme"`
in the application part instead of the activity one!!

Answer (score 1):

Use that `Toolbar` like this: without (`A` just lowercase `a`):

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:background="@android:color/black" />
```

And then, since you already have:

```
Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar
```

It should work then.But, this will causes the problem:

```
Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar
```

Also, add this too(in the `Styles.xml`):

**Updated:**

```
<resources>
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <!-- <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item> using for FullScreen Activities -->
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>

    </style>
</resources>
```

Comment: Done, but still getting the same error message. BTW, thanks for helping me.

Comment: I added in stlyes.xml the last bit, but error again

Comment: No, i'm sorry, i forgot to add more information :), Updated. it should work, if it didn't, perhaps you are missing something.Can i see your whole `Styles.xml` ? it will help us.

Comment: I've just updated the styles.xml after your advise. That one is the whole styles.xml. My application was working ok, then I decided to add a simple toolbar with appcompat and is not working anymore.

Comment: And i'm still not getting what is this: `android:windowFullscreen` and what is the purpose of using? can you remove it and then try? i've updated the answer, it should work without that `android:windowFullscreen`.

Comment: Linx64 I've just found out the problem, I replied to my post with the solution, many thanks anyway +1 for you!